# Was Buddhism the dominant religion of India for one thousand years?

Tags: history, books

I read in a book by `Amartya Sen` `'The Argumentative Indian'`, ([link](http://books.google.com/books?id=agk63AlLmIgC&lpg=PA187&vq=thousand&pg=PR12#v=snippet&q=thousand&f=false)) that Buddhism was the dominant religion of India for about a 1000 years, and that foreigners referred to India as a Buddhist kingdom. Is it true?

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Buddhism#mediaviewer/File:Buddhist_Expansion.svg) map from wikipedia shows that Buddhism was influential only in a small part of North-East India, and not at all in the southern or western part. Kindly provide online references, if possible.

Comment: This question seems to be about history, not about Buddhism. It might be better to ask it on [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [This question has now been asked on History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/17772)

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia's [History of Buddhism in India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Buddhism_in_India) says that:

- [Maurya Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurya_Empire) (322 BCE–185 BCE) was Buddhist
- [Kushan Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kushan_Empire) (30 CE–375 CE) was Buddhist

[Decline of Buddhism in India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decline_of_Buddhism_in_India) says that decline began in late [Gupta Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gupta_Empire) (320 CE–550 CE)

So for more than 500 years, there were Buddhist empires ruling the whole of what's now India except its southern tip.